# Android TextView fill_parent

Tags: android, layout, textview, fill-parent

I need to build a layout similar to the following:

[image: Desired layout]

The three rows in the left are TextViews, whose total height is unknown at the beginning. The element in the right should be any widget that can change its background color dynamically. And it should span its height to fill the parent.

How can I achieve this? What widget should I use to display the color? And what layout?

I tried the following using a TextView for the right element, but it doesn't fill the parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtRow_color"
    android:layout_width="10dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ff23cf"      
    android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRow_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtRow_color"
        android:textColor="#FFFF66"
        android:text="@string/nullstring" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRow_Tweet"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtRow_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtRow_color"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/nullstring" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".8">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/te" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text1" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tile" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text2" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/e" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@color/green">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to use two nested LinearLayouts, something like this, I'll just stub it out with some of the important attributes:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation= "horizontal">
  <LinearLayout android:orientation= "vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Since you're just displaying a solid color, there are a few other views that would work instead of the image view, this is just one example.  You can use `setBackgroundColor()` on the ImageView to change it's color.

Comment: Thanks. I used LinearLayout as mentioned in another solution and it worked.